# Dynamic paint - looping canvas animation

Tags: animation, dynamic-paint

the problem seems simple, but I can't find a solution or similar topic.

How can I loop the canvas animation (dynamic paint) so that frame number 1 looks similar to frame 180 (end), I mean a similar influence of the brush on the canvas during the entire animation.

Of course, the "rain" is a brush, and a "puddle" is a canvas. The brush is looped, but for a canvas it is impossible to set negative frames (-180 for example)

**EDIT:** Sorry, I can't add attachments at the moment: "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"

Comment: I might try this: Run the simulation for 360 frames, and then use the baked results twice, but blend the starting half of one with the ending half of the other for a total of 180 frames.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! I think I understand what you mean, but can you help me what exactly should I do? How can I combine baking etc. sorry, it's only my first month with Blender :)

Comment: In the shader. You have two Image Texture nodes loaded with the sequence, but with different starting points, and a MixRGB with the factor animated from one to the other.